# How to remove reference column (=1st column) from products table in order confirmation email in Prestashop 1.7.6.1

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Can anybody tell me how to remove the first column from {products} table in Prestashop order_conf email in PS 1.7.6.1?

Also, where to edit column width of {products} order detail table - when I change order_conf.html it has no effect. Table dimensions are given by inline styles:

```
<tr style="background-color:#EBECEE;">
        <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em;width:15%;"></td>
        <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em;width:30%;"></td>
        <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em;width:20%;"></td>
        <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em;width:15%;"></td>
        <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em;width:20%;"></td>
</tr>
```

But I have no idea where these styles come from as it is not from classes/PaymentModule.php as most likely was in earlier versions as I've read.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The list of products in the order confirmation mails comes from mails/{iso_code}/order_conf_product_list.tpl file
- Width of the each column of the product list table is from the same file so if you change the width in the order_conf.html then it will not have any effect. If you want to change the width then change it from mails/{iso_code}/order_conf_product_list.tpl file and make sure you don't have override version of order_conf in your theme.
  Hope these answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Based on your answer I found out, that list of all products in order confirmation email is really given by order_conf_product_list.tpl file, exept when as a payment is chosen cash on delivery plus module when it gives me layout from my original post. So now I am going to look for answer why, but it shouldn't, hopefully, be that difficult now. So thanks again for answer, solved my issue.